# Why won't 'twoways' in plm produce fixed effects for group as well as time?

Tags: panel-data, plm

When I do the two ways model in the `plm` package, my understanding is that it should have fixed effects for group and time, but when I manually look at the fixed effects it only produces fixed effects for the group variable. For example, using the canned data in the plm package:

```
> data("Produc", package = "plm")
> zz <- plm(log(gsp) ~ log(pcap) + log(pc) + log(emp) + unemp,
            data = Produc, index = c("state","year"),model='pooling')
> qq <- plm(log(gsp) ~ log(pcap) + log(pc) + log(emp) + unemp,
            data = Produc, index = c("state","year"),model='within',effects='twoways')
> length(fixef(zz))
Error in fixef.plm(zz) : fixef is relevant only for within models
> length(fixef(qq))
[1] 48
> length(unique(Produc$state))+length(unique(Produc$year))
[1] 65
```

My expectation is that the last two lines should be equal, i.e. that there should be year and state fixed effects. Why are they different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is explained in the help for `fixef`, use `?fixef` to view it:

For a two-ways model, `fixef`'s default behaviour is to output the group ("individual") fixed effects. If you want the time fixed effects, use `fixef(your_model, effect = "time")`.

Picking up your example, take heed you do *not* estimate a two-way fixed effects model as the argument is called `effect` rather than `effects` (with a s). So use:

```
qq <- plm(log(gsp) ~ log(pcap) + log(pc) + log(emp) + unemp,
          data = Produc, index = c("state","year"), model ="within", effect = "twoways")
length(fixef(qq)) # 48
length(fixef(qq, effect = "time")) # 17
```

You can check with `summary(qq)` which model you estimated as the first line of its output will tell you the model: "Twoways effects Random Effect Model" in this case.

Comment: This is very helpful. One quick question about the last thing you say. Are you saying that I should put 'effect' as the argument for twoways or 'effects'? I think in my example I do effects, and so do you in yours, but I am confused by your response bcause it sounds to me like you are saying I should use effect.

Comment: Use `effect` (without s)  - good catch. I edited my answer accordingly. `effects` (with s) is an unknown argument processed in the elipsis (...) and `plm` will fall back to default behaviour which is a one-way model.